# Need a solution C++ Loops and conditions

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I want the program to show an error when, from the options, somebody inputs a number out of the range....

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <process.h>
#define PI 3.14159265359
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int a, b, c, d, e, f;
     long double loga, logarithm, sine, cosine,tan;
     char ch, ch1;
     cout << "\nMy Friend Calci:-";
     cout << "\n1. Addition (1st + 2nd)";
     cout << "\n2. Subtraction (1st - 2nd)";
     cout << "\n3. Multiplication (1st * 2nd)";
     cout << "\n4. Division (1st/2nd)";
     cout << "\n5. Logarithm";
     cout << "\n6. Natural Sine";
     cout << "\n7. Natural Cosine";
     cout << "\n8. Natural Tangent";
     cout << "\n9. Exit";
     do
     {
         cin >> ch;
         if (ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4')
         {
          cout << "\nEnter the first and the second numbers respectively:-";
          cin >> a >> b;
         }
         else if (ch == '5' || ch == '6' || ch == '7' || ch == '8')
         {
          cout << "\nEnter the angle (in Radians) or the number you want to calculate Log/Sine/Cosine of:-";
           cin >> loga;
         }
        switch (ch)
        {
        case '1':c = a + b;
            cout << "Sum =" << c;
            break;
        case '2':d = a - b;
            cout << "Difference =" << d;
            break;
        case '3':e = a*b;
            cout << "Product =" << e;
            break;
        case '4':f = a / b;
            cout << "Quotient =" << f;
            break;
        case '5':logarithm = log(loga);
            cout << "log(%d) =" << logarithm;
            break;
        case '6':sine = sin(loga*PI / 180);
            cout << "sin(%d) =" << sine;
            break;
        default:cout << "Wrong Choice My Friend... Now DIE!!!!!";
            cout << "\nOr enter a valid one";
            break;
        }
    cout << "\nWant to Enter MORE (y/n) ?????";
    cin >> ch1;
    if (ch1 == 'y' || ch1 == 'Y')
        cout << "Then enter a choice:";
} while (ch1 == 'y' || ch1 == 'Y');
return 0;
}
```

I need the program to show the error message when someone enters any other numeric value tha 1 to 9 and at the same time, show the two different messages for 1 to 4 and 5 to 8 as shown in the code and if possible then in minimum no. of loops... (not that there are any less already.. heheheh...)

UPDATE!!!!!!
After a few tweaks now whats happenin is dat if i enter 156, it takes 1 as the input and asks for an input, if i enter 1 then it gives me the sum of 56 and 1 and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> do
>      {
>          cin >> ch;
> ```

Add:

```
         if (ch < '1' || ch > '9')
         {
             cout << "Unknown option " << ch << "! Please retry: " << endl;
             ch1 = 'y';
             continue;
         }
```

> ```
>          if (ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4')
>          {
>           cout << "\nEnter the first and the second numbers respectively:-";
>           cin >> a >> b;
>          }
> ```

Or if you want to preserve the current format then instead of

> ```
>     default:cout << "Wrong Choice My Friend... Now DIE!!!!!";
>         cout << "\nOr enter a valid one";
>         break;
> ```

Write something like:

```
default:cout << "Wrong Choice My Friend... Now DIE!!!!!";
    cout << "\nOr enter a valid one ";
    ch1 = 'y';
    continue;
```

Comment: but then what should i do with the default part of the switch....anyways thanx for help

Comment: @RaviSharmaRs Note that you are missing `case` for '7', '8' and '9'. In this case the `default` option is useless. You can either remove it or throw an exception, since you should never get there.

Comment: @RaviSharmaRs I eddited my answer with the usage of the `default` option.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick suggestion. You could change your input type from char ch to int ch. A char is one character. If you input 10, it will only take '1'. If you input 22. It will only take '2'. The rest of the input is used for the function. For instance if you entered 22. Selected option '2'. a = 2. b = waiting on user.
Also you are not providing a proper exit function. You can add to your switch condition.

```
int a, b, c, d, e, f;
long double loga, logarithm, sine, cosine, tan;
char ch1;
int ch; // int ch instead of char ch
cout << "\nMy Friend Calci:-";
cout << "\n1. Addition (1st + 2nd)";
cout << "\n2. Subtraction (1st - 2nd)";
cout << "\n3. Multiplication (1st * 2nd)";
cout << "\n4. Division (1st/2nd)";
cout << "\n5. Logarithm";
cout << "\n6. Natural Sine";
cout << "\n7. Natural Cosine";
cout << "\n8. Natural Tangent";
cout << "\n9. Exit";
do
{
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch == 1 || ch == 2 || ch == 3 || ch == 4)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter the first and the second numbers respectively:-";
        cin >> a >> b;
    }
    else if (ch == 5 || ch == 6 ) // remove 7 and 8 because there is not matching function in switch statement. Pointless to accept user input.
    {
        cout << "\nEnter the angle (in Radians) or the number you want to calculate Log/Sine/Cosine of:-";
        cin >> loga;
    }
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 1:c = a + b; // change to int instead of char input for all cases
        cout << "Sum =" << c;
        break;
    case 2:d = a - b;
        cout << "Difference =" << d;
        break;
    case 3:e = a*b;
        cout << "Product =" << e;
        break;
    case 4:f = a / b;
        cout << "Quotient =" << f;
        break;
    case 5:logarithm = log(loga);
        cout << "log(%d) =" << logarithm;
        break;
    case 6:sine = sin(loga*PI / 180);
        cout << "sin(%d) =" << sine;
        break;
    case 9: exit(0); // exit your program 
        break;
    default:cout << "Wrong Choice My Friend... Now DIE!!!!!";
        cout << "\nOr enter a valid one";
        break;
    }
    cout << "\nWant to Enter MORE (y/n) ?????";
    cin >> ch1;
    if (ch1 == 'y' || ch1 == 'Y')
        cout << "Then enter a choice:";
} while (ch1 == 'y' || ch1 == 'Y');
```